# Refresh All (graphs and power query) using SAS Code

Tags: excel, refresh, powerpivot, datamodel

Is it possible to update all graphs and data model in an excel template, using SAS Code? I don't have access to use DDE and wanted to avoid using VBA.

For more detail, I have excel(xlsx) files that I update with new SAS data on a recurring basis and I do not want to go into each file in order to refresh. I tried clicking "Refresh upon opening" for connections and pivots and it still doesn't work.

Currently, I use libname to update my tables, and then copy the template over to a new location, but when I open the final file, graphs are not updated.

```
libname out xlsx "&RPTPATH./Template/&TMPLT.";
data out.TBL_DTS;
    set Dates;
run;
data out.TBL_POPULATION;
    set TBL_POPULATION;
run;
data out.TBL_QUESTIONS;
    set TBL_QUESTIONS;
run;
data out.TBL_QUESTION_RESULTS;
    set TBL_QUESTION_RESULTS;
run;

libname out clear;

* create copy of template file;
filename in "&RPTPATH./Template/&TMPLT."; 
filename out "&RPTPATH./&MH_FLDR./&RPTNM.";
/* copy the file byte-for-byte  */
data _null_;
  length filein 8 fileid 8;
  filein = fopen('in','I',1,'B');
  fileid = fopen('out','O',1,'B');
  rec = '20'x;
  do while(fread(filein)=0);
     rc = fget(filein,rec,1);
     rc = fput(fileid, rec);
     rc =fwrite(fileid);
  end;
  rc = fclose(filein);
  rc = fclose(fileid);
run;

filename in clear;
filename out clear;
```

I tried using the "Refresh upon opening" selection in connections and in pivot chart options, and copying the file over first before updating tables.